# Import .CSV file containing sporadic use of quotation marks into MS Access

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, adodb

I am importing/inserting data from a .csv file to a MS Access database.
Some of the fields in the .csv file has quotation marks in them, others not (if the field contains a comma, the field is placed within quotation marks).
The fact that only some fields contain quotation marks causes the import to skip each row which contains a field with quotation marks (fields without quotation marks are imported fine).

**How do I import/insert all fields (irrespective of quotation marks)?**

Here is my connectionstring to dabase:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.open = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=somefolder\database.accdb"
```

Here is my query that inserts data from .csv file (UTF-8) into database (.csv file is indeed comma-separated):

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Query = "INSERT INTO [table] SELECT * FROM [" & strCSVFileName & "] " _
        & "IN """ & strCSVFolder & """ ""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;CharacterSet=65001;""" 
rs.Open Query, conn
```

**Brief background**

The database will be updated daily by colleagues of mine with no interest in VBA or databases. Hence, the import/insert has to be automated and run from a macro contained in Excel.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up parsing the .csv file with Adodb Stream (since FileSystemObject does not seem to be able to handle UTF-8). I have access to the .csv files also as tab-delimited, which I though would be easier to handle with Adodb Stream (but which I knew I could not correctly read with above described approach). However, tab-delimited .csv files seem to difficult to deal with everywhere - so I stuck with the comma-delimited file format and did what Gustav suggested; cleaned up each row to get rid of quotation marks.

Now that I have it working, I am happy I have gone this way, since I have been able to correct other problems in the .csv files, and since each .csv file only take about 3 seconds to parse, clean and insert into database.

Comment: In that case, I also have the option of downloading the data as tab-delimited (rather than comma-delimited). The tab-delimitted version does not contain quotation marks. My proposed solution above won't work for tab-delimited files, but if I am going to use FileSystemObject to parse the file anyway, I might as well use the tab-delimited file. Thanks for your input Gustav.

Comment: Gustav; if you post your comment as an answer, I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no safe and simple method to import inconsistent data.

Thus, open the file as text, read line by line applying whatever validation, converting, and/or correction you may find needed, and then append the field of the line to the table.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed `Text Qualifier` field in the Import Text Wizard. If you select the quotation mark `"` there, MS Access will import the data correctly and will recognize that commas enclosed in quotation marks are not delimiters.

I'm not sure how to apply this in VBA though.

[image: Text Qualifier in Access' Import Text Wizard]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try importing data into Excel first to see whether it gives correct results. If correct, then, you can import data from Excel directly to Access.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I am slightly afraid that the operations will take "too long", since the import contains 4 .csv files with around 2000 rows each. Having them run through excel might slow down the process more than I like. But I will definitely try to import to Excel and see how the data then looks.

Comment: Switch off screen updating, automatic calculations, and other stuff that usually slows down the code. From my own experience: switching those stuff off helped me to reduce code execution from 30-40 minutes to less than 30 seconds.

Comment: The files were also "messy" when opened in Excel, so I opted for Gustav's approach above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with csv files from VBA, take a look up to [this project](https://github.com/ws-garcia/VBA-CSV-interface). I can understand you need to get the raw data from a CSV over Excel, a fast option is to load the CSV records into an array and then dump it to a Worksheet.

Try this:

```vb
Sub ImportRecords_RFC4180()
    Dim CSVix As CSVinterface
    Dim filePath As String
    
    filePath = "C:\Demo.csv" 'Change this to suit your needs
    Set CSVix = New CSVinterface 'Create new instance
    Call CSVix.OpenConnection(fileName) 'Open a physical connection to the CSV file
    Call CSVix.ImportFromCSV 'Import data
    Call CSVix.DumpToSheet 'Dumps the data to the current Workbook's new Worksheet starting at named "A1" range.
    Set CSVix = Nothing 'Terminate the current instance
End Sub
```